# Axis, Java Messaging Service, and MIME Headers

Tags: java, web-services, jms, axis

We are consuming a Java Messaging Service based webservice via Axis, and the webservice returns an XML document wrapped in MIME headers. This causes an issue because we cannot recognize the return value. The solution found on Google states to move `mail.jar` and and `activation.jar` to the `classpath`. However, we use a hosted solution, and the provider [Demandware] will not let us move the jar files. Is there another solution for this issue? Is it possible to prevent JMS from wrapping the return in MIME headers (Oddly, we have more control over the third-party webservice than our hosted solution).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want Demandware to act as SOAP web service server, don't you? However, this is not supported in the current version of Demandware. Only REST-based web services are supported at the moment and can be consumed by clients.

It is also not possible to customize this from my point of view. This might also be the reason why you are getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTTPClient for communication with the WebService and create/parse the SOAP envelopes with Demandware script code, but it is tedious thing to do.
You may also check on Demandware XChange portal (closed site, requires registration) for Webservice Framework by Jorge Matos.

Also it may help to use command-line AXIS toolkit and see what the stubs generated are.
As AXIS is used on Demandware servers, when you include the wsdl file in your cartridge webservices folder, you will be seing the same stubs that are getting generated and used internally from Demandware.